# how to access object from inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, inheritance

Hello I want to access an object from inheritance in my project,but I cant find a way
My page is ;

```
public partial class siteler_page : siteDynamic
{
    public static string pageType = "contentpage";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

And the main class is ; (i want to access that pageType paramter in onpreinit)

```
public class siteDynamic : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public siteDynamic()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {

    // I want to access the pageType in here 

        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated,thans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to define an abstract property and let the child classes override it (`siteDynamic` should be an `abstract` class):

```
public abstract class siteDynamic : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     public siteDynamic()
     {
        // ...
     }

     public abstract string PageType { get; }

     protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
     {
           string type = this.PageType;

           // ...

           base.OnPreInit(e);
     }
}

public partial class siteler_page : siteDynamic
{
     public override string PageType
     {
          get
          {
               return "contentpage";
          }
     }

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          // ...
     }
}
```

Comment: thx,I tried your advice but it gives error  'siteDynamic.PageType.get' is abstract but it is contained in non-abstract class 'siteDynamic'

Comment: @slayer35 Updated my answer. Your parent class should be `abstract` to define `abstract` members.

Answer (score 1):

this will not work because your parent class siteDynamic is called an initialized first before your child class siteler_page. At least this is how you set it up. In order for this to work set your parent class should have a property in the parent class then override the base class method and set the value there.

```
public abstract class siteDynamic : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string PageType { get; set; }

 protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnPreInit(e);
 }
}

public partial class siteler_page : siteDynamic
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.PageType = "contentpage";
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
}
```

Comment: You can look Matias's solution worked very well for me ,thanks